# Pinned/Stickied column in Bootstrap 3, using just CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way **without** using Bootstraps mobile-first / hard-coded column re-ordering (`push`/`pull`), to have a "pinned" `<div class="col-# sticky-div...>"` that will always be on top of other columns when it goes into collapsed mode?

And to do this only with CSS or another route that doesn't require knowing the structure/number of the columns in advance - this is meant to be dynamic and the user would only need to select a "sticky" div, in which case the following would occur:

**Uncollapsed (SM, MD, LG)**
[image]

**Collapsed (XS)**
[image]

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/2sx0frsx/3/)**

Again we can't use the `push` / `pull` classes as we won't know the column structure, the user will be using a drag-and-drop type of building for these layouts (which enforce bootstrap columns) and we need to let them specify a "pinned" column when the divs collapse on smaller views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a semi-fix, which involves picking a bootstrap size (and below) at which to have stickied/pinnable content. For my use case I chose to allow anything under `col-sm-#` (so size XS) to be pinnable/stickied by adding the class `sticky-div`.

The TLDR is we just turn that `row` and its `<div class="col-..`'s *temporarily* into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) then use the `order` property.

**[JSFiddle Demo (Has additional examples)](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/oktg4zcx/5/)**

**JS**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div>
        1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div>
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sticky-div">
      <div>
        3 (stickied)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div>
        4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div>
        5
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div>
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  [class*="col-"] {
    order: 2;
  }
  .sticky-div {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

**Want to use a different size?**

If you want your content to collapse on a certain size (like SM), then find the break point of the column size above it (MD) and set that as your `max-width` point. The break points are currently defined by **[Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)**

**Cheat Sheet:**

1. If your smallest size is using `col-sm-#`, then your content can stick/pin on XS, so use: `max-width: 768px`
2. If your smallest size is using `col-md-#`, then your content can stick/pin on SM, so use: `max-width: 992px`
3. If your smallest size is using `col-lg-#`, then your content can stick/pin on MD, so use: `max-width: 1200px`